# Whats wrong with this JavaScript if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I'm learning JavaScript and I'm just playing around - bear with me here, I'm trying to learn some concepts so I'm hacking together a simple "Magic 8 ball" game. I thought if I used `math.random` I could generate a random number and use an if/else statement to show an "answer" based on the random number generated behind the scenes. The idea is for the user to never see the random number of course. My issue though is...no matter what I do, the script always shows the very first if/else answer though. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a link to my codepen example for reference: 
https://codepen.io/celtninja/pen/NvmmNg

```js
var answer = prompt("What is your question?");
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
var realAnswer = number;


if(realAnswer = 20) {
    document.write("It is certain");
} else if (realAnswer = 19) {
    document.write("It is decidedly so");
} else if (realAnswer = 18) {
    document.write("Without a doubt");
} else if (realAnswer = 17) {
    document.write("Yes definitely");
} else if (realAnswer = 16) {
    document.write("You may rely on it");
} else if (realAnswer = 15) {
    document.write("As I see it, yes");
} else if (realAnswer =14) {
    document.write("Most likely");
} else if (realAnswer = 13) {
    document.write("Outlook good");
} else if (realAnswer =12) {
    document.write("Yes");
} else if (realAnswer = 11) {
    document.write("Signs point to yes");
} else if (realAnswer = 10) {
    document.write("Reply hazy try again");
} else if (realAnswer = 9) {
    document.write("Ask again later");
} else if (realAnswer = 8) {
    document.write("Better not tell you now");
} else if (realAnswer = 7) {
    document.write("Cannot predict now");
} else if (realAnswer = 6) {
    document.write("Concentrate and ask again");
} else if (realAnswer = 5) {
    document.write("Don't count on it");
} else if (realAnswer = 4) {
    document.write("My reply is no");
} else if (realAnswer = 3) {
    document.write("My sources say no");
} else if (realAnswer = 2) {
    document.write("Outlook not so good");
} else {
    document.write("Very doubtful");
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Also, a side question, the above is also how I calculate a random number between 1 and 20?

Comment: Please include your whole code in the question, not just a link to it.

Comment: For testing the equality, use `==` (or maybe `===`) instead of `=`

Comment: Replace `realAnswer = 20` with `realAnswer == 20`, I think `switch` is more useful. in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `=` you assigning value to `realAnswer`. So in your code comparison happens in next order

```
realAnswer = 20;
if (realAnswer) {
    // where comparision will return always true 
    // false will be only when realAnswer = 0
}
```

Instead use "triple equal" - which sure that values are equal without possible type conversion.
[Comparison Operators (JavaScript)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/comparison-operators-javascript)

```
if (realAnswer === 20) {
    // do something
}
```

In your particular case `Map` will be more readable and maintainable approach then `if` or `switch`

```
const answers = new Map();
answers.set(20, "It is certain");
answers.set(19, "It is decidedly so");
answers.set(18, "Without a doubt");
// ... and so on
```

Then

```
const realAnswer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
const answer = answers.get(realAnswer);

document.write(answer);
```

Comment: @JafferWilson true, but using `===` can be nice habit, which possible save some time in the future

Answer (score 3):

`if(realAnswer = 20)`

`=` is an assignment operator

try `==` is equal operator

```
if(realAnswer == 20){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your `if/else` statement is, you are using `=` assignment instead of `==` for comparison.
you should just change it to:

```
if (realAnswer == 20) {
   . . .
}
```

However, since you are using multiple `if` statements for `realAnswer`, I strongly suggest you use `switch/case` instead. This will improve readability of you code (***see snippet below***):

```js
var answer = prompt("What is your question?");
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
var realAnswer = number;

switch (realAnswer) {
  case 20:
    {
      document.write("It is certain");
      break;
    }
  case 19:
    {
      document.write("It is decidedly so");
      break;
    }
  case 18:
    {
      document.write("Without a doubt");
      break;
    }
  case 17:
    {
      document.write("Yes definitely");
      break
    }
  case 16:
    {
      document.write("You may rely on it");
      break;
    }
  case 15:
    {
      document.write("As I see it, yes");
      break;
    }
  case 14:
    {
      document.write("Most likely");
      break;
    }
  case 13:
    {
      document.write("Outlook good");
      break;
    }
  case 12:
    {
      document.write("Yes");
      break;
    }
  case 11:
    {
      document.write("Signs point to yes");
      break;
    }
  case 10:
    {
      document.write("Reply hazy try again");
      break;
    }
  case 9:
    {
      document.write("Ask again later");
      break;
    }
  case 8:
    {
      document.write("Better not tell you now");
      break;
    }
  case 7:
    {
      document.write("Cannot predict now");
      break;
    }
  case 6:
    {
      document.write("Concentrate and ask again");
      break;
    }
  case 5:
    {
      document.write("Don't count on it");
      break;
    }
  case 4:
    {
      document.write("My reply is no");
      break;
    }
  case 3:
    {
      document.write("My sources say no");
      break;
    }
  case 2:
    {
      document.write("Outlook not so good");
      break;
    }
  default:
    {
      document.write("Very doubtful");
      break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Also, there is another way for your example. Making use of arrays:

```js
var answer = prompt("What is your question?");
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
var realAnswer = number;

var answers = ['', "Very doubtful", "Outlook not so good", "My sources say no",
  "My reply is no", "Don't count on it", "Concentrate and ask again",
  "Cannot predict now", "Better not tell you now", "Ask again later",
  "Reply hazy try again", "Signs point to yes", "Yes", "Outlook good",
  "Most likely", "As I see it, yes", "You may rely on it", "Yes definitely",
  "Without a doubt", "It is decidedly so", "It is certain"
];

document.write(answers[realAnswer]);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

This IMO has the least line of codes. Just bear in mind that you need to provide the answers into an array and give an empty string to the first element of the array. Since you are generating random numbers from 1-20, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The best idiom for testing equality goes like this:

```
if (20 === realAnswer)
```

rather than

```
if (realAnswer === 20)
```

Then, when you make an error like

```
if (20 = realAnswer)
```

the interpreter / compiler will tell you that you can't assign to the literal value 20 and you'll know you have a problem.

Code defensively!

Comment: In most projects in worked on, the comparisons are rarely between a _constant value_ and a variable. Most comparisons are between variables, and for thoses cases your solution does not work. In genereal a linter shout be used in js projects that checks for common pitfalls like that.

Comment: `20 === realAnswer` nice workaround, but very bad for readability

Comment: @Fabio It's surprising how quickly you get used to this form of expression.  In C/C++/Java it is common enough among programmers, once magic numbers are replaced by constants.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Nested IF Else better to use Switch Case:

```
var answer = prompt("What is your question?");
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
var realAnswer = number;

switch (realAnswer) {
    case 20:        
        document.write("It is certain");
        break;
    case 19:
        document.write("It is decidedly so");
        break;
    case 18:        
        document.write("It is decidedly so");
        break;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....


  default :{
      document.write("Very doubtful");
  }
}
```

Comment: Those are not nested if else blocks. They all belong to the same if statment. `if(val==20) { ... } else { if(val==19) { ... } else { ... }}` would be nested. Beside that you do not explain why the code of the OP fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(realAnswer = 20) {
    document.write("It is certain");
}
```

what's wrong with this is, you're assigning value and not comparing it. Please check javascript Comparison Operators below or visit [Comparison Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

```
Operator Description               Comparing    Returns 
    ==      equal to                    x == 8       false  
                                        x == 5       true   
                                        x == "5"     true   

    ===     equal value and equal type  x === 5      true   
                                        x === "5"    false
```